# Something like $smarty->assign without smarty

Tags: php, smarty, variable-assignment

I know the question might be silly but I've read so many rumors about smarty lags and bugs I don't really want to get into all that, but I do want to use comfortable template for my scripts.

What I am looking for is a function set or just a script so I could use something like $smarty->assign , so I could use generated codes in my templates for example {$username} instead of whole `<?php $username ?>`

Is there any lighter option doing that other than getting a whole template engine

Comment: There are any number of [*Template Engines*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=php+template+engine&safe=off) available, if you are concerned about "rumors" concerning Smarty.

Comment: Yes, use PHP. It's a templating language.

Comment: @meagar PHP used as a templating language tends to be a horrid mash-up, and I would care to see less of it.. a separate template system (even one that utilizes PHP syntax/processing) is a step in the Right Direction.

Comment: Well the thing is that they are huge, of course I will have to use one of the template engines available , but only if there is no simpler ways doing that

Comment: @user2864740 No, it's really not. PHP as a templating language is only a horrible mashup if you mix front- and back-end logic in your views. That isn't PHP's fault, that's the programmer's fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should reconsider your opinion.

First rule is that all template engines and other scripts have some bugs and using everything (even OOP) may make your code running slower. Even PHP has many bugs (some not fixed for many years) and you probably still use it. So either you think only about bugs and speed or about functionality and good practises and you cannot always achieve both.

The second thing is as somebody already mentioned in comment, there are many PHP template engines. Smarty is the most popular and best known but there are also others as for example Twig. Which one will be better for you? It's hard to say. Which one will have best performance? It's hard to say - many performance tests are contradictory and looking at one of them you may read that Smarty is the best and the quickest and in the other one, that Smarty is the slowest.

Creating your own template engine doesn't have much sense I think. You mentioned you would like for example use `{$username}`. But what about loops and control structures? Do you want to code them all in your template engine? What about performance in that case? Are you sure your template engine will be better, quicker and won't have any bugs?

Those all questions are important because you need to know that always using any kind of library it's quite possible it will have some bugs and not always creating your own library will be better (probably usually it won't).

If you still think about creating your own "template engine" I don't think it's necessary. You should simple use native PHP code to achieve this. If your code will be used in PHP 5.4+ no matter what's the setting instead of `<?php echo $username ?>` you can simple use `<?= $username ?>`. In previous versions you need to make sure that you have `short_open_tag` set to 1. Is this settings better than `{$username}`? Probably not, but I think it's good enough to use it instead of creating your own template engine.

The most important thing is to separate logic form displaying. So in your pure PHP file (without HTML/CSV/... code) you simple should take data from database, make calculation and so on and in template file (which may be also PHP file but mixed with HTML) you simple use `<input type="text" name"test" value="<?= $test_value ?>" />`.

What you can also do is creating your own class and simple in pure PHP file use:

```
$o = new Output();
$o->assign('test_value', $username);
```

and later in your PHP file mixed with HTML syntax you may use:

```
<input type="text" name"test" value="<?= $o->test_value ?>" />
```

Using your own class you can also easier prepare your data for displaying it - you can run for example htmlspecialchars, htmlentities and similar functions to make your output secure.

Comment: I'll take a look in to Twig and Smarty than , hopefully they won't overload my scripts, didn't really think that way that I'll have plenty of bugs in own template engine with very limited functions. 
Thanks